# Attribute is not being renamed by this code in LDAP

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ldap, jndi, openldap

```
/**
 * ModifyRDN .java
 * Sample code to demostrate how ModifyRDN/ModifyDN works.
 */

import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;

import java.util.Hashtable;

public class ModifyRDN 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://myLdapServer:389/dc=myDomain,dc=com");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=directory manager");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");

        /*
          Whether the old RDN attribute values are to be retained 
          as attributes of the entry, or deleted from the entry
        */
        env.put("java.naming.ldap.deleteRDN", "true");  // default is 'true'

        try {
            /* Create the initial context */
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

            ctx.rename("cn=John Smith,ou=Sales,ou=People", 
                       "cn=John Cougar Smith,ou=Sales,ou=People");

            /* Close the context when it's done */
            ctx.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My error list is as follows

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'cn=name1 name2,ou=mycompany'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3025)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2946)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2752)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_rename(LdapCtx.java:700)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentContext.p_rename(ComponentContext.java:708)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeContext.rename(PartialCompositeContext.java:266)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeContext.rename(PartialCompositeContext.java:255)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.rename(InitialContext.java:395)
    at ModifyRDN.main(ModifyRDN.java:22)
```

Answer (score 1):

i dont now what you code should do, but the exception told you you put in only

```
cn=John Smith,ou=Sales
```

instead of

```
cn=John Smith,ou=Sales,ou=People
```

or not?

Answer (score 0):

Error Code 32 is the object not found, or bad DN path error.  You need to give it a real and valid DN to use.

Did you santize the output such that the error line:
remaining name 'cn=name1 name2,ou=mycompany' changed the values, or is that the real error code?

It looks odd, as no where else do you reference that path in your code.  I note you are using a domain (probably AD) with dc=mydomain,dc=com.

You probably can get away with relative paths, but I doubt it during a rename, where you are changing the RDN, it is important to know exactly what you are changing (and implicitly) to where.